# Material design icons with webpack and angularjs loading wrong icons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, material-design, webpack

I am using material design icons (https://materialdesignicons.com/) and loading them using webpack in my angularjs app. Gulp serves my webpage. My webpack configuration file has the following code for fonts:

`{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, loader : 'url-loader' }`

The problem I am facing is that the wepage that is getting rendered has wrong icons displayed. When I use `file-loader` instead of `url-loader`, I get following warning in the console.

`Failed to decode downloaded font, OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT`

Unable to figure out the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
{ test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
```

You can try this out for your fonts. This worked for me.

Comment: For anyone struggling, this was the right answer for me. I was trying to use bootstrap-material-design with my app but webpack wouldn't pack the Material-Design-Icons. This did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two loaders:

```
{ test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" }
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```